# Is quoting a book in a question or answer copyright violation?

Tags: discussion, legal

I read a book that answers one of my questions, and I would like to quote it as an answer. Is that illegal?

Thanks.

Comment: In any question where you ask about the legality of anything you should probably include your location in the question otherwise people reading your question might make incorrect assumptions.

Comment: @ho: ..Which leads to another question: Am I accountable for my content or is SO accountable for it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See this article on [Fair Use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use), which describes the ways copyrighted materials can be freely used without infringing.

The line between fair use and copyright infringement is a fuzzy one but, in general, if the amount of copied text is small, and you cite the original author, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The Wikipedia entry goes into detail on Fair Use in the US, says that Israel is the only other country with a fully developed legal concept of Fair Use, and gives quick summaries of the law in France, Israel, and South Korea.  It seems likely that Oren A is in an English-speaking country, but that doesn't mean one under US law.

Comment: @David: Thanks for the compliment on my English skills, but as you can see at my profile, I'm actually from Israel.

Answer (score 3):

IANAL, but generally speaking and in most countries, quoting a few paragraphs from a book constitutes fair use *as long as* you provide a citation.

Reproducing several pages or an entire chapter would be outside the bounds of fair use.